# SetExpressCheckout Minimum Variables

Tags: variables, paypal, sandbox, minimum

I am getting an error 10413 "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. I can't find what totals are different, so I want to eliminate the variables that I do not need in order to simplify and find the variables that aren't matching.  What are the absolute minimun variables needed to complete a transaction in paypal sandbox?

Comment: You don't need to pass anything but the payment amount.

Answer (score 0):

The following must be true in your API request.

ITEMAMT + SHIPPINGAMT + HANDLINGAMT + TAXAMT = AMT

If that math does not work out then you will get the error you are seeing.

You can eliminate all of those and just send an AMT on its own, but then you can't include line item details.  If that's not important, then you'd be just fine.  I always prefer to send line item details, though, so that I have it available in the PayPal transaction details.

So again, as long as that math works out then you would be fine.  You need to look at your request and see what values you have for those, add them up, and you'll probably find that they don't equal the AMT value you sent.